# Selenium C# sem metodo main adequado

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Eu tô fazendo umas aulas de automação com Selenium com a linguagem C# e quando vou compilar pede o método main adequado que já tentei por de várias maneiras

```
using System; 
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class NomeDoProjeto
    {
        public IWebDriver driver;
        private string baseURL;
        public string screenshotsPasta;
        int contador = 1;

            //Método para capturar screenshot da tela
            public void Screenshot(IWebDriver driver, string screenshotsPasta)
            {
                ITakesScreenshot camera = driver as ITakesScreenshot;
                Screenshot foto = camera.GetScreenshot();
                foto.SaveAsFile(screenshotsPasta, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
            } 

        [SetUp]
        public void SetupTest()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            baseURL = "https://www.google.com.br";
            screenshotsPasta = @"C:\Users\cciola\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TesteGit\Evidencias\";
        }

        public void capturaImagem()
        {
            Screenshot(driver, screenshotsPasta + "Imagem_" + contador++ + ".png");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TeardownTest()
        {
            try
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
            }
        }

        [Teste]

        public void NomeDoTeste()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/intl/pt-BR/about/");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            capturaImagem();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Main é ponto de entrada do programa, é por onde o seu programa começa. [Leia isso aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/).

Comment: E onde está o `Main()`?